# import database in webpack

Tags: php, ajax, webpack

I am new in webpack development and want to ask is it possible to import
database in webpack.config.js

In My config js file I just want to change the filename dynamic
and every user login with mysql and they will see different HtmlWebpack with different CSS and images that they save before.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "html/index.html",
    filename: __dirname + "/index.html"

new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {from: 'assets/css/medium-bootstrap.css', to: __dirname + '/build/elements/css/medium-bootstrap.css'}
])
```

Can the filename index.html can change dynamically to [html page value from mysql database] ?

1. Can it be use with ajax?
2. Can it be use with session or cookies from client?
3. Is the database plugin I can import to webpack.config.js?

Thanks all in advance. Kelly